# mySQL get all possible combinations of certain rows

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations

I have a strange request in mySQL. I found many ways to do this for pairs of combinations or a certain other number by adding more joins, but I am wondering if there is a dynamic way of doing it for any number of combinations.

To explain if I have a table table has 1 column (column_id) and (column_text)

```
Id | Text
--------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | B
4  | B
5  | A
```

Then by running a procedure GetCombinations with parameter A should yield:

```
CombinationId | Combinations
---------------------------
1             |      1
2             |      5
3             |      1,5
```

by running a procedure GetCombinations with parameter B should yield:

```
CombinationId | Combinations
---------------------------
1             |      2
2             |      3
3             |      4
4             |      2,3
5             |      2,4
6             |      3,4
7             |      2,3,4
```

Obviously the larger the number, then I expect an exponential increase of results.

Is such a query even possible? All I could find was results using Joins limiting the length of each result to the number of Joins.

Thank you

### UPDATE

I have found an article [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/sql-query-for-combinations-without-repetition) but the maximum number of combinations should be small (max 20 or so). In my case with a 100 combinations I calculated that it would produce: 9426890448883247745626185743057242473809693764078951663494238777294707070023223798882976159207729119823605850588608460429412647567360000000000000000000099 rows (lol)

So I will classify my answer as infeasible

However is there a way to get this result with max 2 combinations?

```
CombinationId | Combinations
---------------------------
1             |      2
2             |      3
3             |      4
4             |      2,3
5             |      2,4
6             |      3,4
```

I have found a query to get all combinations using JOIN but I am not sure how to produce the combination id and also how to get the individual rows.

### UPDATE 2

Solved it using

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS 'CombinationId'
cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
```

And I did the query with UNION ALL

Comment: You could probably do it with a stored procedure. Other than that, the only way to loop is by joining with a table that has as many rows as the repetitions you need.

Comment: Do you have a table that contains lots and lots of numbers?

Comment: I found this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/sql-query-for-combinations-without-repetition which looks promising but it seems to have a limit in the number of combinations.
My maximum is about potentially 100 numbers.

Comment: Although that T-SQL solution is impressive, (my)SQL may not be the right tool for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to generate the [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the set of all elements with field `Text == <parameter>`. As you already found out, this number grows exponentially with the length of the input array.

If you can solve it in other language (say, php), take a look at this:

[Finding the subsets of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092781/finding-the-subsets-of-an-array-in-php)