# How to get all possible combinations from a tag and item table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table like below

```
============
item | tag
-----+------
111  | amaretto
-----+------
111  | blueberry
-----+------
222  | amaretto
-----+------
333  | blueberry
-----+------
333  | chocolate
-----+------
444  | chocolate
-----+------
444  | amaretto
-----+------
555  | chocolate
-----+------
666  | blueberry
-----+------
666  | amaretto
-----+------
666  | chocolate
============
```

The columns `item` and `tag` together constitutes a composite primary key. Lets imagine like the the item as an ice cream and the tags as the available flavors. For example, if I search for amaretto (in the case of ice cream), I want to display all possible combinations in which amaretto ice cream is available, like amaretto, amaretto+chocolate, blueberry+amaretto etc. If I search for tag `amaretto`, I want to display all possible combinations like;

```
amaretto (222)
amaretto,blueberry (111)
amaretto,chocloate (444)
amaretto,blueberry,chocolate (666)
```

And the combinations `amaretto,blueberry` and `blueberry,amaretto` are same.

How can I do this? Do i need additional tables? I use PHP+MySQL.

Comment: What SQL can do is retrieve all the flavours of a given ice cream, by querying the primary key. Once you collected all the flavours, enumerating all the possible combinations is up to you.

Comment: @kuroineko do u have any solution?

Comment: if you know probability than i think it have n number of probability of combination of this

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998962/mysql-get-all-possible-combinations-of-certain-rows

Comment: @Calimero Actually, that's a slightly different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.tag) tags 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.item = a.item 
 WHERE b.tag = 'amaretto' 
 GROUP 
    BY a.item;
+------------------------------+
| tags                         |
+------------------------------+
| amaretto,blueberry           |
| amaretto                     |
| amaretto,chocolate           |
| amaretto,blueberry,chocolate |
+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To solve the OP's amended question, a rare instance of DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query together...:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tag ORDER BY a.tag) tags 
  FROM mytable a 
  JOIN mytable b 
    ON b.item = a.item 
   AND b.tag <= a.tag 
 WHERE b.tag = 'amaretto' 
 GROUP 
    BY a.item;
+-------------------------------------+
| tags                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| amaretto,blueberry                  |
| amaretto                            |
| amaretto,chocolate                  |
| amaretto,blueberry,chocolate        |
| amaretto,blueberry,chocolate,pastry |
+-------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Note that multiple identical combinations *can* be symptomatic of a lack of normalisation.

Comment: I have added new entries to my table which can be found here: http://freetexthost.com/40ow4gkf5c and when I run the query, I get duplicate results, `444  amaretto,chocolate` and `888  chocolate,amaretto` which are same (irrespective of 444 & 888). Here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xShne.jpg . I want to elimitate duplicates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tt.item,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  tt.tag) FROM mytable tt
 JOIN mytable ttt 
ON tt.item=ttt.item
GROUP BY tt.item
HAVING SUM(tt.tag='yourtag')>0
```

One solution is to GROUP BY the results of GROUP_CONCAT if they are ordered first

```
SELECT MIN(item),tags FROM
(SELECT  tt.item,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  tt.tag ORDER BY tt.tag) tags FROM mytable tt
 JOIN mytable ttt 
ON tt.item=ttt.item
GROUP BY tt.item
HAVING SUM(tt.tag='amaretto')>0)x
GROUP BY tags
```

Comment: what are `t`, `tt` and `ttt`?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ Highly imagniative aliases

Comment: @Mihai, if my table name is like mytable, where I have to provide my table name `mytable`?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ sqlfiddle is down,this is tested on my machine

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ This is the demo with your inital data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e1611/5

Comment: I have added new entries to my table which can be found here: http://freetexthost.com/40ow4gkf5c and when I run the query, I get duplicate results, `444  amaretto,chocolate` and `888  chocolate,amaretto` which are same (irrespective of 444 & 888). Here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xShne.jpg . I want to elimitate duplicates. How can I do this?

Comment: The flavor combinations of items 444 and 888 as well as 666 and 999 are same irrespective of their order of appearance. So instead of 7 results in total, I need only 5. http://i.stack.imgur.com/4S13O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) and then using [LIKE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/like.php) statement.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT item, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag) as TagCombinations
FROM tbl
GROUP BY item ) A
WHERE TagCombinations LIKE 'amaretto%'
```

Comment: Since you are using pre aggregate filtering you are removing all the non amaretto rows