# PHP Given increasing numbers in this order, calculate all possible combinations

Tags: php, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

the problem is simple, but is giving me a headache, 
I have for example a 4 numbers array, but I can have up to 20 numbers.
Given in the following order:

```
       [1]  [2]  [4]  [5]
```

I need to obtain all combinations of this numbers, except numbers can't be permuted, so the order is maintained, I'll give an example of what I'm trying to obtain:

```
     [1] [ ] [4] [5]
     [1] [2] [ ] [5]
     [ ] [2] [4] [5]
     [ ] [ ] [ ] [5]
     and even
     [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

The resulting array will contain sub arrays of the resulting numbers

Update: the empty arrays are optional,

```
          [1] [4] 

               Or

           [2] [4] [5]
```

Would be ok also, less complications.

Comment: My benchmark results : 

Sebastian Walker
20 numbers array
124.32486701012 microtime
1048576 results


Sumurai8
wonkyPermutations
20 numbers array
38.228344917297 microtime
1048576 results

Thank you guys.

Comment: Can please give what is the final output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do can be done quite easily, if you realize that what we want to accomplish is in fact recursive. For each subpart we need to make a choice: We add a space, or we add a number from our list.

```
function wonkyPermutations( $numbers ) {
  return wonkyPermutationsWithSpaces( Array(), $numbers, count( $numbers ) );
}

function wonkyPermutationsWithSpaces( $prefix, $numbers, $maxlength ) {
  if( $maxlength == 0 ) {
    //We can't add anymore
    return Array( $prefix );
  } else {
    //We have two choices: We either add a space, or we don't.
    $prefix1 = $prefix;
    $prefix1[] = NULL;
    $prefix2 = $prefix;
    $prefix2[] = $numbers[0];
    $suffix1 = wonkyPermutationsWithSpaces( $prefix1, array_slice( $numbers, 1 ), $maxlength - 1 );
    $suffix2 = wonkyPermutationsWithSpaces( $prefix2, array_slice( $numbers, 1 ), $maxlength - 1 );

    return array_merge( $suffix1, $suffix2 );
  }
}

$a = Array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
var_dump( wonkyPermutations( $a ) );
```

Comment: Yup, I somehow mis-interpreted the question. The main gist of the answer is the same though. You'll just need to add `array_slice( ... )` at the other suffix, and you can remove one of the edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what I did is I took [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996895/list-all-combination-possible-in-a-php-array-of-boolean-value-in-php) code to find out all the possible "number is there" / "number is not there" combinations, like the following:

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0
and so on...
```

Afterwards I applied this to the `input` arrays contents.

```
<?php
//First of all, find out all possible combinations of "number is there" and "number is not there"

$input = ["1","2","4","5"];

$empty = " "; //Value to insert if "number is not there"

$length = sizeof($input); //How many numbers are in the array

$combinations = pow(2, $length); //Number of possible 1/0 combinations

$sequence = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $combinations; $x++) {
    $sequence[$x] = str_split(str_pad(decbin($x), $length, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT));
}

//Alright, so now we have to apply these combinations to our $input array
$output = [];


foreach($sequence as $combo){
    $output_combo = [];
    foreach($combo as $key=>$val){
        if ($val == 1){
            //"number is there"
            array_push($output_combo, $input[$key]);
        }else{
            //"number is not there"
            array_push($output_combo, $empty);
        }
    }
    array_push($output, $output_combo);
}

//There you go! The variable $output contains your array.

//Display the array (You can leave this part out...)
foreach($output as $combo){
    foreach($combo as $val){
        echo "[" . $val .  "] ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Check out this PHPFiddle - it works with as many numbers as you want.  Just make sure the `$empty` variable contains the value that you want to have if the number is not there.

Simply click this link and choose "Run": http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fdtn-u5jv

Comment: Thank you would be enough ?

Comment: You consume twice the memory needed to generate this list, but it seems to work.

Comment: You might want to put the code in your answer in case that link will become dead in the future.

Comment: Thank you guys, can't accept more than 1 answer, i will benchmark and select the best solution.