# How to find sum of each subset in php?

Tags: php, arrays, math, set, subset

I want to compute the sum of all possible sub-set form array.

```
$array= Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 6 ); //changing

function powerSet($array) {
 // add the empty set
    $results = array(array());
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        foreach ($results as $combination) {
            $results[] = array_merge(array($element), $combination);
            $total= array_sum($results); // I try this
        }
        echo $total; // I try this
    }
    return $results;
}
```

The above code is used to find subsets. I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092781/finding-the-subsets-of-an-array-in-php#). I just add `array_sum` but show 0's how to find each subset total? any way ?

Comment: Can you explain with an example? what will be the input and output?

Comment: @BhaskarJain check the question upadated

Comment: All you need to do is `$ans = array_map("array_sum", $results);` at the end of the function this will give you array of all the sum of the subset (I vote to reopen and try to edit - if you want official answer please make new (and more clearer) post)

Comment: ^ it does not matter from where you get an array. Do it after function call. In the case `$ans = array_map("array_sum", powerSet($array));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$result` in the function is array of arrays so you cannot just use `array_sum` on it. In order to sum each of the sub-set you need to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) together with [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

You can do it in the end of the function - just add `print_r(array_map("array_sum", $results));` as last line (if  you want it as output).

I liked @splash58 comment about using it outside the function with:

```
$ans = array_map("array_sum", powerSet($array));
```