# Laravel Factories - Avoiding Duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Good Afternoon,
I'm looking for some help please with Laravel 10.

I am looking to write a database seeder which will use the `Incidents` factory to generate new incidents.
Each `Incident` should have additional models created called `SkillUsed` during their creation.

Lets say the skill_id are:
`1`, `2`, `3`.

The catch here is an Incident factory should not have duplicate skills. For example: 1,2 is fine but 1,1 is not.

Database Seeder:

```
protected function seedIncidents() : void {
        // Add some incidents made-to-scene, excluding scheme vehicles and case reviews and no POCUS skill.
        $incident = Incident::factory()->state([
            'incident_snr' => 0,
        ])->count(50)->create()
        ->each(function($incident) {
            SkillUsed::factory()
                ->count(fake()->numberBetween(1,5))
                ->create();
        });
```

Skill Used Factory:

```
public function definition(array $attributes = []): array
    {
        $incident = $attributes['incident_id'] ?? Incident::inRandomOrder()->first()->value('incident_id');
        $existingSkillsUsed = Incident::find($incident)->SkillsUsed()->pluck('sid')->toArray();

        $skill = Skill::whereNotIn('sid', $existingSkillsUsed)->inRandomOrder()->first();

        return [
            'sid' => $skill->sid,
            'incident_id' => $incident,
            'deleted_at' => fake()->optional($weight = 0.2)->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-6 months', $endDate = 'now', $timezone = null),
        ];
    }
```

My problem is how to access the previously created `Incident` model to ensure the Skill isn't duplicated.

Much appreciated :)

Comment: How many skills can they have? 0? 3?

Comment: There are set skills within the database (Skill model) for which there is only currently 3. 
So, a minimum of 1, max of 3. :)

Comment: This Q&A may be possibly related to your problem and  its solution, [Finding the subsets of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6092781/), since you're looking for all non-empty subsets of an array or collection.

Answer (score 0):

I can see few issues in your implementation so I encourage you to re-read the documentation about the factories especially [factory relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#factory-relationships).

That said I propose some changes to your `SkillUsedFactory`, I can see you're running many queries like `inRandomOrder`, `find`, `SkillsUsed()` which isn't ideal for factories so I suggest you remove those and replace them with a placeholder that can be fed from the outside

```php
// SkillUsedFactory

public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'sid' => 0,
        'incident_id' => 0,
        'deleted_at' => // stays the same,
    ];
}
```

Then in your database seeder there are few changes to achieve creating a unique skills.

You do not need to access the previously created `Incident` you just need to store them in an array in this case something like `$existingSkillsUsed`

Try this modified seeder, there are slight changes from your implementation for example I replaced `each` with `afterCreating` which is a factory method rather than looping on a collection.

```php
protected function seedIncidents(): void
{
    Incident::factory()
        ->state(['incident_snr' => 0])
        ->count(50)
        ->afterCreating(function ($incident) {
            $this->createUniqueSkills($incident);
        })
        ->create();
}

protected function createUniqueSkills(Incident $incident): void
{
    $numberOfSkills = rand(1, 5);
    $existingSkillsUsed = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfSkills; $i++) {
        $skill = $this->getUniqueSkill($existingSkillsUsed);
        $existingSkillsUsed[] = $skill->sid;

        SkillUsed::factory()->create([
            'sid' => $skill->sid,
            'incident_id' => $incident->id,
        ]);
    }
}

protected function getUniqueSkill(array $existingSkillsUsed)
{
    return Skill::whereNotIn('sid', $existingSkillsUsed)
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->first();
}
```

I have not tested this code because I am not sure where else you're using the `SkillUsedFactory`, but if it doesn't it should get you the idea.